# removing class in 2 separate functions

Tags: jquery, html

I have this script that changes the hamburger (menu icon) to an X when it is open and the standard three lines when it is closed, (standard stuff).

The X state has a class of nav-toggle called ".active"

I have defined the body html as class .metro so when you click on the main screen when the menu has been opened it will close the menu and also get rid of the class "active" , (back to 3 lines and menu closed) ...

.... can someone tell me why this code doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var state = false;
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if(!state){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            state = true;
           $('.nav-toggle').addClass('active');
           $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            state = false;
             $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

$( '.metro' ).click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
               $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

the methods for collapse and expand are defined http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/

the html for the hamburger and the button is ...

```
<div class="navbtn"> <p><a class="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>Menu</p>
    </div>
```

I know that .metro includes everything in the body and this includes the menu itself which is why it isn't working so perhaps it needs to include .metro css background img to be more speific for the cliable area of the body withouth including the menu.

Comment: Seems like state is internal to the function where it is defined. Need to move it up the scope. Don't you get en error on trying to access it?

Comment: if i take the .metro function out it does work... i think it is because the body html includes the emnu itself and this confuses the code.. i need to make .metro.css:background-img instead , just don't know how

Comment: I meant the "var state". Did you try declaring it before the "ready"? Regarding your comment - yeah, the click are getting overridden. Would advise scoping more tightly.

Comment: ah fair point , if i declare the var before ready then the clickable area would be navbtn which is what i want instead of the outline of the hamburger, nav-toggle

Comment: how do i go about this without ripping it out of the working function ?

Comment: ...i am also moving the background image that makes up the body into it's own class so that i can still make the area outside the menu clickable to close it .

Comment: yup changing the class from .metro worked a treat ... how do i declare the vars before hand though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically .metro being the html body covers everything within it INCLUDING the actual menu... this confuses the code as your basically saying click on the body to close or the menu and it doesn't know which one so it basically doesn't run the code.... declaring the main body space in a seperate div or class worked !